# Scroll view panning prevents pinch gesture?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer

I'm creating an image tiling library for use in a game project, to fit into our existing framework. I'm currently using a UIScrollView (with an empty view) to allow me to hijack the nice physics for panning around with bounce, but I had to implement my own zoom using the pinch gesture recogniser (for reasons I won't get into).

Here's the thing, though - when I'm panning with one finger, adding a second touch and trying to zoom does nothing. I need to be absolutely still before it will allow me to zoom. When the user is panning around the image, my pinch gesture recogniser never fires unless the pan has totally finished.

Does anyone know a way around this, that doesn't involve scrapping the UIScrollView and implementing my own pan as well?

Here's my scrollViewDidScroll function:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    viewingBounds.origin.x = scrollView.contentOffset.x;
    // Transform the y from UIKit coordinates into OpenGL coordinates
    viewingBounds.origin.y = world.height - viewingBounds.size.height - scrollView.contentOffset.y;
    [parentScene update]; // Render the image
}
```

My gesture recogniser is added directly to the scroll view in init:

```
[scrollView addGestureRecognizer:[[[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didReceivePinch:)] autorelease]];
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the delegate of your GestureRecognizer objects, and in the delegate implement this method:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer;
```

And have it return YES.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried anything from Apple's [ZoomingPDFViewer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ZoomingPDFViewer/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010281) or [PhotoScroller](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotoScroller/Introduction)? In Photo Scroller the images are tiled and tile and you zoom in. Hopefully there is something you can get out of it. If you have trouble unzipping the file try downloading from Xcode.

I think I also found a few other people doing something close:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383757/scaling-panning-a-uiimageview-using-pinch-and-swipe-gestures-free-code

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/22500/how-to-zoom-and-pan-when-you-pinchswipe-across-scr.html

http://technology.blurst.com/iphone-multi-touch/

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yeah, I've looked through both of them, but the problem is that they both just use the scroll view to render their scene, whereas we want complete control of rendering in our own OpenGL system. That's where the problem lies - the zooming values in the UIScrollView entirely depends on the view you pass it in viewForZoomingInScrollView, and expects you to be happy with what it gives you - even passing it a blank view doesn't fix our problem. To be honest, I think I'll just have to remove the scroll view and re-implement some of its functionality using touches. Bit of a pain, but not too bad. :)

Answer (score 0):

Hey Adam, I don't know if you have rewritten anything yet but I have some alternatives for you [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584463/how-does-zooming-panning-and-rotating-work), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4820156/opengl-es-3d-model-zoomed-doesnt-pan-correctly-in-uiscrollview), [here](http://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/ubbthreads.php?ubb=showflat&Number=133318&page=1), worse case ask someone the same question [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/). Hope that helps.